# V5 -- Data driven Tags?

Tags: pester, pester-5

In a Pester v5 implementation, any way to have a data driven tag?

My Use Case:

- Operating on larger data sets
- To have all tests runable on a data set
- To be able to run against a specific element of my data set via the Config Filter

My Conceptual example:

```powershell
Describe "Vehicles" {
    Context "Type: <_>" -foreach @("car","truck") {
        # Should be tagged Car for iteration 1, Truck for iteration 2
        It "Should be True" -tag ($_) { $true | should -betrue }
    }
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works for me, so the answer seems to be, yes you can do that. Usage examples:

```
~> Invoke-Pester -Output Detailed
Pester v5.3.1

Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery found 2 tests in 12ms.
Running tests.

Running tests from 'C:\Users\wragg\OneDrive\Desktop\so.tests.ps1'
Describing Vehicles
 Context Type: car
   [+] Should be True 18ms (1ms|17ms)
 Context Type: truck
   [+] Should be True 19ms (2ms|16ms)
Tests completed in 129ms
Tests Passed: 2, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0


~> Invoke-Pester -Output Detailed -TagFilter car
Pester v5.3.1

Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery found 2 tests in 12ms.
Filter 'Tag' set to ('car').
Filters selected 1 tests to run.
Running tests.

Running tests from 'C:\Users\wragg\OneDrive\Desktop\so.tests.ps1'
Describing Vehicles
 Context Type: car
   [+] Should be True 9ms (4ms|5ms)
Tests completed in 66ms
Tests Passed: 1, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 1


~> Invoke-Pester -Output Detailed -TagFilter truck
Pester v5.3.1

Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery found 2 tests in 11ms.
Filter 'Tag' set to ('truck').
Filters selected 1 tests to run.
Running tests.

Running tests from 'C:\Users\wragg\OneDrive\Desktop\so.tests.ps1'
Describing Vehicles
 Context Type: truck
   [+] Should be True 21ms (1ms|19ms)
Tests completed in 97ms
Tests Passed: 1, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 1
~>
```

Comment: Shame on me -- it does work as you listed! I was scoping the $_ at the wrong level of my test structure (my example was far more simple than my actual implementation)

Thank you!

Comment: Don't fret, I learnt something new that I think could be pretty useful in the future, so thank you for the interesting question!